# Выбрать нужные поля, а не нужные скрыть

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо когда выбирается `value="МИН">` то в tematsprId были видны только value="0" и value="1"

А когда выбирается `value="РОС">` то в tematsprId были видны только value="2" и value="3"

```html
<select id="sel" name="username" onclick="numberone()">
  <option value="0">Назначить</option>
  <option value="ИНГ">ИНГ</option>
  <option value="МИН">МИН</option>
  <option value="РОС">РОС</option>
  <option value="РО">РО</option>
  <option value="СИ">СИ</option>
  <option value="Т">Т</option>
</select>

<select id="tematsprId" name="tematsprId" style="display: block;">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Льготное1</option>
  <option value="2">Льготное2</option>
  <option value="3">Льготное3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Какое отношение имеет Java к вопросу?

Comment: Во первых, это больше похоже на поиск решения на JavaScript. Во вторых, приведите ваш код, в котором есть ошибка, html разметка не дает никаких представлений. Разве что с 0 написать нужно всю логику.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#sel').change(function() {
    const curVal = $(this).val();
    const curOpt = $('option[value="' + curVal + '"]', this);
    const vals = curOpt.data('val');
    const options = $('#tematsprId > option').hide();
    if (vals) {
      options.each(function() {
        const val = parseInt(this.value);
        if (vals.indexOf(val) != -1)
          $(this).show();
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" name="username">
  <option value="0">Назначить</option>
  <option value="ИНГ">ИНГ</option>
  <option value="МИН" data-val="[0,1]">МИН</option>
  <option value="РОС" data-val="[2,3]">РОС</option>
  <option value="РО">РО</option>
  <option value="СИ">СИ</option>
  <option value="Т">Т</option>
</select>

<select id="tematsprId" name="tematsprId" style="display: block;">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Льготное1</option>
  <option value="2">Льготное2</option>
  <option value="3">Льготное3</option>
</select>
```